# Interpretation of Steps (1/2) failed in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running an sql query on snowflake, which has been running for more than 24 hours.
When I go to 'Profile Overview', I see Steps (1/2, Failed):

[image]

However, under 'Details' tab, I see that the status of the query is still 'Running'.
Can someone please explain whether the query is still running or has there been some error ?

Comment: Have you refreshed your browser when you are on the full query history page?  Sometimes that page doesn't refresh correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This must be retrying after failing on a first attempt. For example, it might have failed on a memory error and would retry internally twice (total three tries) before either successfully completing or failing with an error (in case all tries fail).

You may reach out to Snowflake Support for looking into this.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is likely resource (memory) intensive.  Something to check in your query would include:
- large sort or large number of sort?
- large group by (or many aggregates?)
- Many Windowing functions with order by?

For a query to be running for many hours, likely it would be best to dig deeper either with help of support (open case), or look for opportunity to review the query pattern.